# SQL if value in a row

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, sql-update, mariadb

I would like to update a row only if a condition on another row is met.

something like:

```
IF (SELECT `allow` FROM `accountlist` WHERE `id`='myid')<'1234' 
       THEN
           IF (UPDATE `accountlist` SET `upvotes`=`upvotes`+1 WHERE `user`='myuser')
               THEN (UPDATE `accountlist` SET `allow`='1234' WHERE `id`='myid');
           END IF;
       ELSE (/*return false*/);
END IF
```

in other words, if *allow* is lower than *1234* on *myid*, increment *upvotes* on another row and if you succeded set *allow* to *1234*, otherwise return false or some error values.

Is it possible to run multiple queries when a condition is met?

Comment: It is very unclear, what you are trying to accomplish. The only way mysql does something "on its own" is by using an event or trigger.  But it can not detect in its own, why your condition is met. so when exactly do you want t run your update

Comment: I going to run it from PHP using prepared statements ('1234', 'myid' and 'myuser' are placeholders binded by mysqli)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need CASE expressions like this:

```
UPDATE `accountlist` 
SET `upvotes` = CASE WHEN `user`='myuser' THEN `upvotes` + 1 ELSE `upvotes` END,
    `allow` = CASE WHEN `id` = 'myid' THEN '1234' ELSE `allow` END
WHERE (SELECT `allow` FROM `accountlist` WHERE `id`='myid') < '1234'
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM `accountlist` WHERE `user`='myuser')
```

Comment: it works but it does not check whether it finds `user='myuser'`, how to fix it?

Comment: There is this: `CASE WHEN user='myuser' THEN...` so it only updates when `user='myuser'`. What else should it check?

Comment: I mean, if the first update works, then do the second. For example if it didn't find `user='myuser'`, he would not update `allow` for `id='myid`... Sorry if I made confusion :(

Comment: Also are you sure that this is MySql and not MariaDB?

Comment: I'm using SQL from phpmyadmin but honestly I'm not sure if it is MySQL or MariaDB... How can I check it and why that doubt?

Comment: `select version();`

Comment: `10.4.11-MariaDB`... you're right! How did you notice it?

Comment: The code I posted initially which you said worked would not work without enclosing the subquery in the where clause inside another subquery. This is a MySql feature.

Comment: `WHERE id='myid' AND allow<'1234` works properly anyway... Is it possible?

Comment: If this condition is satisfied in the same row yes. But this is not clear in your question.

Comment: Ok I made a couple of tests and you're right... Using `WHERE id='myid' AND allow<'1234'` the second `CASE` statement work but not the first one, unless it is on the same row where `id='myid'`, so I had to change it with `WHERE (SELECT allow FROM accountlist WHERE id='myid')` and now it works properly. Thank you again and happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `update` statement with `where` clause :

```
UPDATE `accountlist` 
     SET `upvotes`= (CASE WHEN `user`='myuser' THEN `upvotes` + 1 ELSE `upvotes` END),
         `allow` = (CASE WHEN `id` = 'myid' THEN '1234' ELSE `allow` END)
WHERE `id`='myid' AND allow < 1234
```

Comment: but I have to check if `allow` is lower than '1234' where `id`='myid'. using the first statement it would check it on `user`='myuser'

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE `accountlist` 
SET `upvotes` = `upvotes` + (`user` = 'myuser'),
    `allow` = CASE WHEN`id`='myid'
                   THEN '1234'
                   ELSE `allow`
                   END
WHERE ( SELECT `allow` 
        FROM `accountlist` 
        WHERE `id`='myid' ) < '1234';
```

Comment: Thank you... but does it check if it finds `user= 'myuser'`?

Comment: @Foxel Of course. ```SET `upvotes` =  `upvotes` + (`user` = 'myuser')``` - adds 1 only when the condition is true.

Comment: I mean that it wouldn't update `allow` if it wasn't able to update `upvotes` because there is not `user='myuser`... Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Don't worry... Problem solved with forpas (thanks anyway)